# Expired provisioning profile

Tags: ios

I have an expired provisioning profile which is managed by XCode. I tried to edit the provisioning profile through Apple Developer website, however the edit button is disabled for provisioning profile managed by XCode. Then I deleted the provisioning profile. However, XCode is not generating a new provisioning profile for me. I am using XCode 7.3.
I manually created a provisioning profile through the website, but I got the error:

```
No matching provisioning profile found: Your build settings specify a 
provisioning profile with the UUID “xxxxx”, 
however, no such provisioning profile was found.
```

Comment: create new provisional profile from Apple Developer website.

Comment: I got the error No matching provisioning profile found

Comment: The thing is how to get XCode to automatically create the provisioning profile instead of creating it manually.

Comment: Then how it is possible to add UDID in provisional profile when it created automatically by XCode.

Comment: The provisioning profile which required UDID was created manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install "AppleWWDRCA.cer" on your Mac.You can download this from following link http://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer

Comment: Please once check in iPhoneConfigurationUtility for expired provisioning profiles and delete them.